# Making a formula in R from a name

Tags: r

I have a bunch of predictors:

```
x<- c("pred1", "pred2", "pred3")
```

I want to write a formula in a for loop as follows:

```
for (i in 1:length(x)){
   glmfit(y~x[i], data = myDF, family= "binomial")
}
```

Now, `myDF` is a data frame where "pred1", "pred2" and "pred3" are columns. Simply putting `x[i]` however does not work.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make a formula out of a string

```
> formula("y ~your_name_here")
y ~ your_name_here
```

You can then pass this on to the formula parameter in `glmfit`.

Here is an example

```
dat<-data.frame(y=rnorm(10), x1=rnorm(10), x2=rnorm(30))
sapply(names(dat)[-1],function(x) lm(formula(paste("y",x,sep="~")), data=dat))


#alternatively using melt from reshape2 and dlply from plyr package
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
dlply(melt(dat, id=c("y")),.(variable), function(x) lm(y ~ value,data=x))
```

Comment: Typically, we'd use `paste` to actually construct the string to be passed to `formula`.

Comment: yeah, sorry, was drafting out an actual example.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use:

```
for (i in 1:length(x)){
   glmfit(eval(parse(text=paste("y~",x[i]))), data = myDF, family= "binomial")
}
```

Explanation:

```
eval(parse(text="2+2"))
```

evaluates, the string provided to the text argument as an R expression, so you can generate the formula you are looking for by constructing the appropriate string, and then evaluating it within glmfit

Comment: Obligatory reference: `library(fortunes); fortune(106)`.

Comment: You should be extremely careful about using parse/eval. This would not be something you want in production code, because you could be susceptible to malicious attacks. Consider if someone where to pass along the following   x<-c("quit(save='no')")
> eval(parse(text=x[1]))

Comment: ^ Yup, so if the string is coming from a user in a production level, don't use this method